# Getting the value from momentJS subtract without a time zone or offset (GMT +0000)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I wish to produce a date 30 days in the past using momentJS - it's pretty easy, I just use the following

```
const date30DaysPast = moment().utc().subtract(30, 'days').toDate(); // Sun Oct 29 2017 13:23:46 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

This is all great however I want the returned date to have no Time Zone or offset, I want the time to be GMT+0000 not as above GMT+0100 (CET) - for example:

> Sun Oct 29 2017 13:23:46 GMT+0000

I wish to force this as I am using testing servers that are in different locations, and rather than take the time from the local browser I just want set a standard time. I thought using the `utc` method would do this for example should I write something like this in my test:

```
const oct4th2017 = moment.utc(new Date('October 04, 2017 11:13:00'));
```

the output is

> Wed Oct 04 2017 09:13:00 GMT+0000

How can I remove the offset / time zone and set it to GMT on my original subtract method? I have tried wrapping in a parent `utc` method like so

```
const date30DaysPast = moment.utc(moment().utc().subtract(30, 'days').toDate());
```

but this doesn't work. I get the momentJS object.

Any advice could be appreciated, should my wording be bad or confusing please say so and I shall reword my question.

Answer (score 0):

You already have your moment.js object without timezone. But the `toDate()` method creates a native Date object, which always has the local timezone (though it has various UTC methods).

Comment: I thought as much, removing the `toDate()` just returns an object, for example, `Moment{_isAMomentObject: ...` I just need to know how to get the value of the date without using the `toDate` method

Comment: or `valueOf()` to get the timestamp in milliseconds since 1st Jan 1970

Comment: or [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/), in general see [Display](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) section of the docs.